# Do I need woocommerce rest api to write a plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, subscriptions

For example, to run my own function when woocommerce action is fired,
Do I need to authenticate first ?

Comment: No you don't need it if you stay inside wordpress. REST API is something that is useful for external communication between for example Wordpress/WooCommerce and a mobile application or a marketing independent software…

Comment: You can simple hook to the actions like `add_action('action_name', 'callback_func', $priority, $accepted_args_numbers)`